# Divisão de duplicatas num Subreport - MSSQL/Crystal Reports

Tags: sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports, sql-server-2008

Gostaria de gerar um relatório de previsão de impostos de PIS e COFINS, que são calculados baseado num código CFOP das notas emitidas num determinado período, mas gostaria de separar essas informações em "blocos", pois posteriormente vou inserir outras informações.

Espero o resultado dessa forma:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                           CRÉDITO                            |
+---------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|  CFOP   |    Descrição   |  Valor Base  |   PIS   |   COFINS |
+---------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+


+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                      DÉBITO - Cumulativo                     |
+---------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|  CFOP   |    Descrição   |  Valor Base  |   PIS   |   COFINS |
+---------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+

+--------------------------------------------------------------+
|                    DÉBITO - Não-Cumulativo                   |
+---------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+
|  CFOP   |    Descrição   |  Valor Base  |   PIS   |   COFINS |
+---------+----------------+--------------+---------+----------+
```

Acredito que para isso precisarei usar SubReports no Crystal Reports, mas não estou conseguindo pensar em como organizar os grupos no relatório e nos subrelatórios. Lembrando que todos os dados serão baseados num mesmo período que será passado como parâmetro.

O SQL utilizado é basicamente igual em todos os relatórios, mudando apenas o valor de porcentagem para base de cálculo dos impostos dependendo da CFOP.

Segue a SQL de exemplo que retorna as NF emitidas (que vão gerar os "blocos" de débito):

```
DECLARE @PIS decimal(5,4) = 0.0165;
DECLARE @COFINS decimal(5,4) = 0.076;
DECLARE @PIS_I decimal(5,4) = 0.0065;
DECLARE @COFINS_I decimal(5,4) = 0.03;

SELECT 
    DataEmissao
    ,CFOP
    ,Base
    ,Natureza
    ,'Categoria' = UPPER(CASE
                    WHEN Base = 'A' THEN 'Imune' 
                    WHEN Base = 'B' THEN 'Deferido'
                    WHEN BASE = 'C' THEN 'Tributado'
                    ELSE '' END)
    ,[Valor Base]
    ,'PIS' = CASE 
                WHEN Base = 'A' THEN [Valor Base]*@PIS_I
                ELSE [Valor Base]*@PIS END
    ,'COFINS' = CASE 
                WHEN Base = 'A' THEN [Valor Base]*@COFINS_I
                ELSE [Valor Base]*@COFINS END

FROM

(SELECT 
    NotasFiscais.DataEmissao
    ,'CFOP' = SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(NotasFiscais.cfop1,' ',''),'.',''),1,4)
    ,'Base' = CASE 
                    WHEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(NotasFiscais.cfop1,' ',''),'.',''),5,1) = 'P' THEN SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(NotasFiscais.cfop1,' ',''),'.',''),6,1)
                    ELSE SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(NotasFiscais.cfop1,' ',''),'.',''),5,1)
                END
    ,'Natureza' = UPPER((SELECT NatOperacao FROM MT_MAZER.dbo.CFOP CFOP_Desc 
                    WHERE REPLACE(REPLACE(CFOP_Desc.CFOP,' ',''),'.','') = REPLACE(REPLACE(CFOP.CFOP,' ',''),'.','') AND 
                        LEN(CFOP_Desc.NatOperacao) = MAX(LEN(CFOP.NatOperacao))))
    ,'Valor Base' = SUM(NotasFiscais.ValorTotalNota)

FROM 
    DB.dbo.NotasFiscais 
    INNER JOIN DB.dbo.CFOP ON NotasFiscais.cfop1 = CFOP.CFOP

WHERE 
    CFOP.Fatura = 'S' AND
    CFOP.Devolucao = 'N' AND
    NotasFiscais.CodEmpresa = 1 AND
    NotasFiscais.Situacao = 'N' AND
    NotasFiscais.TipoNota = 'S'

GROUP BY 
    NotasFiscais.DataEmissao
    ,REPLACE(REPLACE(NotasFiscais.cfop1,' ',''),'.','')
    ,CFOP.CFOP
    ,NotasFiscais.CodEmpresa) Impostos
```

Comment: Como se define a informação "Crédito/Débito etc" ? Se for possível estar na mesma sql bastaria criar umGRUPO no Crystal.

Comment: É possível fazer a busca na mesma SQL sim, mas eu preciso fazer a busca por SubRelatórios pois preciso dispor o relatório principal na forma de Balanço Patrimonial posteriormente.

Comment: Não vi a relação entre os fatos, desculpe. Pessoalmente uso subs quando a base de dados difere  por algum motivo. Nunca tentei mas creio que mesmo um balanço pode ser feito em CR , desdecque bem estruturado.

Comment: Ok, acredito que o que estou querendo fazer agora eu consiga fazer num mesmo relatório, mas como faria um balanço como [esse](http://juliobattisti.com.br/tutoriais/rodrigosfreitas/conhecendocontabilidade077_clip_image001.jpg) sem usar nenhum sub relatório? Mais especificamente, minha dúvida é como fazer duas colunas lado a lado, se as linhas são diferentes para cada uma.

Comment: Eu faria um balanço, a priori , usando running totals num rel suprimendo detalhe a apenas imprimindoma seção de página (page),